# KeyError: 'ANDROID_APP_PATH'

Tags: android, python, kivy, qpython

I've been programming some Kivy/Python apps on my Motorola Moto G mobile phone.
I've got a few handy little apps, that have been working OK for a few months.

Today, I launched one of the apps - through the QPython interface, and it didn't work.
So, I tried another of my apps and that failed to launch for the same reason. In fact, all of them fail to launch for the same reason.

The error shown on screen ends with:

> File "/QPython/core/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in **getitem**
>
> KeyError: 'ANDROID_APP_PATH'

I presume that something on the phone has taken an upgrade - and broken something.
I assume that is the case because this problem affects all of the Kivy apps I was using.

Anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Did you remove/switch SD cards?

Comment: Where in your code do you use `ANDROID_APP_PATH`? This seems to not exist.

Comment: @Ryan : No I didn't do anything with an SD card.

Comment: I don't use ANDROID_APP_PATH directly in my code. But, kivy, and possibly the twisted library does.

Comment: I also have a Nexus 7. And my code works ok on that. So I really suspect the Moto has upgraded python, or qpython, or kivy and something has broke.

Comment: Looking at site-packages/kivy/__init__.py there is this line 'user_home_dir = environ['ANDROID_APP_PATH']' . That looks like my problem.

Comment: what I don't understand is that ANDROID_APP_PATH appeared in __init__.py in 2012 !!!! . But, my Motorola phone has recently taken an update and this is now causing a problem. Surely that environ variable MUST have been there when I first started using kivy just a few months ago.

Comment: Nick did you find a solution?

Comment: @Abbas - No, nothing yet.

Comment: Anybody there? bump !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have
`#qpy:kivy`
part in the first line.
At least that was what happened to me.
I suppose that is because QPython is finding what type of app is it.

Comment: Woohoo, yes, that's got it working. Thanks very much.